# how to insert value into table field from another table field in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to have some query like follow

```
insert into statistic (uid) values(select `id` from `users` where `name`='$name')
```

but it doesn't work. It gives the following error.

> `#`1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'select id from users where name='job')' at line 1

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you get some sort of error message? It would be VERY helpful to us if you included that....

Comment: yes @gwin003: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select `id` from `users` where `name`='job')' at line 1

Comment: Your single quotes look screwy.  ` vs '

Comment: @dpfarhad: Please remember to always add in error messages (and other useful information) when you ask your question. If you forget one (as here) then please edit it into the question, rather than appending it into the comments (otherwise readers have to read a potentially long set of comments to appreciate the state of the problem).

Comment: @mikeY - backticks are fine in MySQL to delimit table and column names.

Comment: @halfer   Didn't know that.  Thanks for the info.  Good stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
insert into statistic (uid) 
 select `id` from `users` where `name`='$name'
```

with no values

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT...SELECT syntax is meant to be used like this:

```
INSERT INTO statistic (uid)
    SELECT `id` FROM `users` where `name` = '$name'
```

The `values` should **not** be used in this case.

See, also, the relevant section in **[MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)**.